# How to add "Enter" key from keyboard to press a html button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a chat application and I want users can send message just by pressing Enter key.
for now, they send message by mouse clicking.

here is my codes :

```
var chat_input_send = document.createElement('button')
        chat_input_send.setAttribute('id', 'chat_input_send')
        chat_input_send.setAttribute('disabled', true)
        chat_input_send.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i>`
        var chat_input = document.createElement('input')
        chat_input.setAttribute('id', 'chat_input')
        chat_input.setAttribute('maxlength', 1000)
        chat_input.placeholder = `${parent.get_name()}. Say something...`
        chat_input.onkeyup  = function(){
          if(chat_input.value.length > 0){
            chat_input_send.removeAttribute('disabled')
            chat_input_send.classList.add('enabled')
            chat_input_send.onclick = function(){
              chat_input_send.setAttribute('disabled', true)
              chat_input_send.classList.remove('enabled')
              if(chat_input.value.length <= 0){
                return
              }
              parent.create_load('chat_content_container')
              parent.send_message(chat_input.value)
              chat_input.value = ''
              chat_input.focus()
            }
          }else{
            chat_input_send.classList.remove('enabled')
          }
        }
```

I know this is the way but I cant make it work in my codes:

anyone can help me?

```
    $('#idoftextbox').keypress(function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 13) {
        //enter has been pressed
    };
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind enter key ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037422/how-to-bind-enter-key-to-callback-in-javascript-without-slowing-down-the-typing)

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box and other tones of dups questions. Please have a look at them using the search box.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate the click on the button. With `.click()`

Replace $('#idoftextbox') with chat_input and then use the keyCode or which property to identify the Enter key press:

```js
chat_input.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 13) {
        // Enter key has been pressed
        chat_input_send.click(); // Trigger the send button's click event
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of the Enter key (form submission)
    }
});
```

So here is the modified code:

```js
var chat_input_send = document.createElement('button')
chat_input_send.setAttribute('id', 'chat_input_send')
chat_input_send.setAttribute('disabled', true)
chat_input_send.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i>`

var chat_input = document.createElement('input')
chat_input.setAttribute('id', 'chat_input')
chat_input.setAttribute('maxlength', 1000)
chat_input.placeholder = `${parent.get_name()}. Say something...`

chat_input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if (chat_input.value.length > 0) {
        chat_input_send.removeAttribute('disabled')
        chat_input_send.classList.add('enabled')
    } else {
        chat_input_send.classList.remove('enabled')
    }
});

chat_input.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 13) {
        chat_input_send.click();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

chat_input_send.onclick = function() {
    chat_input_send.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    chat_input_send.classList.remove('enabled');
    
    if (chat_input.value.length <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    parent.create_load('chat_content_container');
    parent.send_message(chat_input.value);
    chat_input.value = '';
    chat_input.focus();
};
```

This code will enable you to send a message by pressing the Enter key while focusing on the chat input field. It triggers the same logic that the "Send" button's click event does.

Hope it helps :D